# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 884 (char 883)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nltk

I want to tokenize and sort reviews by keywords, but there is a problem with opening json and programs throw an error: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 884 (char 883). 
The files test2.json and keywords.txt are here:
https://github.com/SilverYar/TransportDataMiner

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk, string, json

st = RussianStemmer()

def tokenize_me(file_text):
    #applying nltk tokenization
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_text)

    #deleting punctuation symbols
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if (i not in string.punctuation)]

    #deleting stop_words
    stop_words = stopwords.words('russian')
    stop_words.extend(['что', 'это', 'так', 'вот', 'быть', 'как', 'в', '—', 'к', 'на'])
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if (i not in stop_words)]

    #cleaning words
    tokens = [i.replace('«', '').replace('»', '') for i in tokens]

    return tokens

with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\keywords.txt') as fin:
    ww = fin.read().split(', ')
    key_words = list(set([st.stem(w) for w in ww]))



with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\test2.json') as fin:
    text = json.load(fin)

with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\bad.json', 'a', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    for dd in text:
        #for d in dd:
        words = tokenize_me(dd['description'])
        split_text = list(set([st.stem(word) for word in words]))
        #break
        tt = list(filter(lambda w: w in key_words, split_text))
        if tt:
            json.dump(dd, fout)
            fout.write('\n')
```

Help me find the error and fix the code.

Comment: Apparently `test2.json` has extra data. Can you share the contents of that file? In the meantime, here's my wild guess: the file was created by multiple consecutive `json.dump` calls, but `json.load` can't read that because combining two legal json strings does not result in a legal json string. `[1,2,3][4,5,6]` is not legal json, for instance.

Comment: I added a link to the files test2.json and keywords.txt

Comment: Help me to change the code if you know how?

Answer (score 1):

You may not do this, because it leads to malformed JSON file:

```
for dd in text:
    if tt:
        json.dump(dd, fout)    # <<-- cannot do this in the loop
        fout.write('\n')
```

Basically it should be written all at once, with a single `dump()` or `dumps()` call.

---

ok, you have to make the large list first, then output it to the file:

```
bad_words_list = []
for dd in text:
    words = tokenize_me(dd['description'])
    split_text = list(set([st.stem(word) for word in words]))
    tt = list(filter(lambda w: w in key_words, split_text))
    if tt:
         bad_words_list.append( dd )

with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\bad.json', 'a', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    json.dump( bad_words_list, fout )
```

Comment: And how can I change the code so that there is no error?

Comment: @Yaroslav i have added the more or less correct version of the code to the answer

Comment: It did not help. I have a problem with this line of code. Error due to this line. I don’t understand how to fix it.

 with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\test2.json') as fin:
       text = json.load(fin)

Comment: @Yaroslav what's the exact error message you got? без конкретного сообщения об ошибке это разговор ни о чём.

Comment: Thank you, Lenik, your answers and the right questions helped me find a mistake. In the end, I decided a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

I decided a little differently - read in the file and format the string into correct json formats:

```
with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\test2.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    formated_text = data.replace('}{', '},{')
    text = json.loads(f'[{formated_text}]')    


with open('C:\\Creme\\token\\bad.json', 'a', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    for dd in text:
        #for d in dd:
        words = tokenize_me(dd['description'])
        split_text = list(set([st.stem(word) for word in words]))
        #break
        tt = list(filter(lambda w: w in key_words, split_text))
        if tt:
            json.dump(dd, fout)
            fout.write('\n')
```